# VC Dimension of the support of a function

Tags: combinatorics, machine-learning

### Problem

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a finite set, the support of a binary function $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is defined as $supp(f)=\{x\in\mathcal{X}: f(x)=1\}$. For any $k\leq \vert \mathcal{X}\vert$, consider the function class $\mathcal{F}_k=\{f: \vert supp(f)\vert \leq k\}$. Find $VC(\mathcal{F}_k)$.

### What I Have Done

The function class $\mathcal{F}_k$ is just all functions that predict no more than $k$ positive labels. In order to find VC dimension of $\mathcal{F}_k$, we need to find the largest restriction of $\mathcal{F}_k$ onto $\mathcal{X}$. Therefore, I have 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}=2^{VC(\mathcal{F}_k)}
$$

However, I do not know how to compute LHS and it seems that it does not have closed form by this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n).

Could someone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the function in $\mathcal{F}_k$ whose support is $X \subset \mathcal{X}$ by $f_X$. Now consider any $X \subset \mathcal{X}$ with $|X| \leq k$. For any $Y \subset X$, $supp(f_Y) = Y$. Thus $\mathcal F_k$ shatters $X$, meaning $VC(\mathcal{F}_k) \geq k$. Note that $\mathcal{F}_k$ cannot shatter any subset $X \subset \mathcal X$ of size $\geq k$, since its support covers at max $k$ points. Hence $VC(\mathcal F_k) = k$.

I don't understand your argument; the expression you wrote would be true if $n$ (which is not defined) was replaced by $k$, in which case the equation simplifies to $VC(\mathcal F_k) = k$.

Comment: Welcome to this site and thank you for your help. I previously thought that $n$ in my description should be $\vert \mathcal{X}\vert$ and the LHS specifies all possible label configurations, but I just realized that $n$ actually should be $k$ since the function class $\mathcal{F}_k$ could give at most $k$ positive labels and the other $\vert \mathcal{X}\vert - k$ are all predicted 0.